# Undefined string in javascript forEach output

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
var tmu, categories = [['Morning','am'],['Evening','pm']], 
days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wen', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'],
fullDay, i;

tmu += '<table>';

categories.forEach(function(ele){ 
tmu += '<tr id="periodTitle">';
tmu += '<td colspan=7 style="text-align:center;">'+ele[0]+'</td>';
tmu += '</tr>';
for(i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
tmu += '<td id="'+days[i]+'-'+ele[1]+'">x</td>';    
}        
});
tmu += "</table>";
console.log(tmu);
```

I am trying to write some code to loop through some table creation however it keeps adding an `undefined` text to the beginning of the loop and I'm not sure why, everything else works great. Any ideas on how this could happen?

The [fiddle link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4XA4/). Thanks for any help in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
var tmu = '';
```

As you are declaring the variable but not assigining a value, tmu will be `undefined` and when you do `tmu += '<table>';`, `tmu` will be coerced to a string - i.e. undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When you use tmu for the first time, use a simple assignment

```
tmu = '<table>';
```

Right now your instruction `tmu += '<table>'` is a shortcut for `tmu = tmu + '<table>'`:
so, you are doing a string concatenation and your `tmu` variable on the right side of this assignment will be evaluated as a string, which value has to be `undefined`, since no previous assignment was done.

Answer (score 0):

initialize `tmu` as string see the [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/z4XA4/1/)

```
**var tmu=''**, categories = [['Morning','am'],['Evening','pm']], 
days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wen', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'],
fullDay, i;

tmu += '<table>';

categories.forEach(function(ele){ 
    tmu += '<tr id="periodTitle">';
    tmu += '<td colspan=7 style="text-align:center;">'+ele[0]+'</td>';
    tmu += '</tr>';
    for(i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
    tmu += '<td id="'+days[i]+'-'+ele[1]+'">x</td>';    
    }        
});
    tmu += "</table>";
   console.log(tmu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the + in the following rule:

```
tmu += '<table>';
```

Change the rule to this and the undefined is gone:

```
tmu = '<table>';
```